# PHP insert on mysql database don't work using PDO (with prepared statements)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm doing a simple website with DropzoneJS for uploading files and insert into my database some info about the uploader, file type ect.
 But the problem is I don't see anything in my '`upload_log`' table after file upload.
Here's my upload.php code :

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $foldername = "../common/uploads";

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $fileupload = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $foldername . $ds;
        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $fileupload;
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        $upload_info = "Filetype : <b>".$fileType."</b> <br>File size : <b>".$fileSize."</b><br>File name : <b> ".$fileupload."</b>";
        add_to_log($_SESSION['username'], 'upload', $upload_info);
    }
```

**The function "add_to_log" :**

`function add_to_log($usr, $type, $info) {
$servername = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'foo';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'foo';
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname.'', $username, $password);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('DB error');
}
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO upload_log(type, user, info) VALUES(:type, :user, :info)');
$req->execute(array(
    'type' => $type,
    'user' => $user,
    'info' => $info
    ));
}`

Comment: Check variable name in function parameter you are using `$usr` but in query you are using `$user`

Comment: 1. Put your query execution into your try and catch block 2. Set error handling right after your connection: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php (`$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`) And tell us if you get any exception

Comment: Change your `catch` block to this: `catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); $errorCode = $e->getCode(); }` to see what the exact problem is.

Comment: ajaykumartak : No i always don't see anything on the db

Comment: I finally found : it was only a include/require errors on my website ! But thanks